# How to move line segment?

Tags: qgis

I use Quantum GIS 1.8.

I have a polyline layer. I can drag&drop polyline nodes by using "Node Tool". 
Is it possible to drag&drop line segments of a polyline in order to preserve line segments' direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Activate editing
- Select the node tool
- click the first node to move
- depress ctrl and then click the other nodes that you want to move (keeping ctrl down)
- drag the selection to the new position

then stop and save edits

Comment: You can also just select the line bit between the two nodes and it will auto select the nodes.

Comment: You can also select the "node tool" and then click the nodes in the "Vertex Editor" (that's easier if you want to select a line with hundreds of points)

Comment: It does not work in OGIS 3.28. We need a newer answer for this question updated to the current versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

- Activate an editing session
- Select the Move Feature(s) tool
- The pointer will change to a plus sign ( + )
- Hover over the line you want to move
- Click and drag the line to a new area
- Release and the line will be where you stopped

Stop and save your edits to make the move permanent

Comment: You have explained how to move the whole polyline but I asked how to move polyline segments (1 or more) - not the whole polyline feature.

Comment: What do you mean by a segment?  A segment is a whole line feature.  Are you talking about a portion of a line, between two nodes?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about "a portion of a line, between two nodes". Mark already solved my problem.